# interrows issue - NaN output when running PyLyrics

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on making lyrics dataset for a project using PyLyrics.

I have imported the dataset, installed PyLyrics and now trying to get Python to generate lyrics for all of the rows in the dataset, but it does not come with any input.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\kk\Desktop\dba lyrics analysis\all_periods_joined_for_lyrics_1.csv', header=1)
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Position', 'Track Name','Artist','Streams','date','period'])


for index, row in df.iterrows():
try:
    from PyLyrics import *
    df.loc[index, 'Lyrics'] = PyLyrics.getLyrics(row['Artist'], row['Track Name'])
except:
    pass
```

And as I get to `print(df)`, the output is the table filled with my headers and 'NaN' instead of any output. Also, the lyrics column does not generate.

What should I do?

I am new to coding, but the paper is due soon, so any and all help is highly appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, please provide some more data - like a small sample of `all_periods_joined_for_lyrics_1.csv` so we can run you program against actual data and reproduce the problem. Also, the indentation of the `try-except` in your `for`-loop looks wrong.
Does `df` contain the right data before the `for` loop is executed?

Comment: Also: Please do the `from PyLyrics import *` at the beginning of your file instead of everytime the for-loop is executed.

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. please see the link for a sample data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/znq3yw26igo57a7/all_periods_joined_for_lyrics_1%20sample.csv?dl=0

Comment: What I mean is that you show us the first (maybe) 3 lines in your question, so that the question is self contained. (You can edit your questions) (Not everyone likes to/can download files from external sources like dropbox).

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine that putting the import of `PyLyrics` into a `try-except` block hides the fact that the `PyLyrics` module is not installed on your machine and thus cannot be imported:

```
try:
    from PyLyrics import *
except:
    # If the import failed we can fix it here - but we just ignore it (pass)
    pass
```

Instead put the `from PyLyrics import *` at the beginning of your file without a `try-except` block so that the script will immediately fail if the package is not installed. Have a look here on how to install the package: https://pypi.org/project/PyLyrics/.

The following code works very well for me.

```py
from PyLyrics import PyLyrics
from pprint import pprint
from pandas import read_csv

songs = read_csv('songs.csv', header=None, names=['Artist','Title'])
for index, row in songs.iterrows():
  print('Getting lyrics for', row.Artist, row.Title)
  try:
    lyrics = PyLyrics.getLyrics(row.Artist, row.Title)
  except:
    lyrics = None
    print('Failed to get lyrics for', row.Artist, row.Title)
  songs.loc[index, 'Lyrics'] = lyrics

pprint(songs)

"""
Getting lyrics for ErrorUndefined DoesNotExist
Failed to get lyrics for ErrorUndefined DoesNotExist
Getting lyrics for Taylor Swift Blank Space
Getting lyrics for Bon Jovi It's My Life
           Artist         Title                                             Lyrics
0  ErrorUndefined  DoesNotExist                                                NaN
1    Taylor Swift   Blank Space  Nice to meet you, where you been?\nI could sho...
2        Bon Jovi  It's My Life  This ain't a song for the broken-hearted\nNo s...
"""
```

**songs.csv**

```
Artist,Title
ErrorUndefined,DoesNotExist
Taylor Swift,Blank Space
Bon Jovi,It's My Life
```

Comment: thanks, it does work, but the output is only for one song, however, I have 2000  rows (artists&songs), so that would be quite a big manual job to go through them one by one. is there any way to get all of the rows done automatically?

Comment: My array `songs` could easily replaced with the content of your CSV file.

Comment: @IrBa Updated the code to read from a csv file. You'll have to update the `names` to match your `columns` and update my usage of `Title` with `['Track Name']` or similar I guess.